# Need to run 3 different ruby files from one single file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting, cmd, watir

I saw the answer in another post but didn't work for me.Below is the error message.

```
C:\watir\OVE>ruby driver.rb
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- ove_scenario.rb (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:
in `require'
        from driver.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: We can not read your mind. You have to provide more information. For start, show us the contents of `driver.rb`.

Comment: Zeljko is right, you need to provide the code you are running. You can try the commands from driver.rb in IRB (run from the c:\watir\OVE directory). You probably have an issue with finding the one_scenario.rb for some reason.

Comment: 'I saw the answer in another post but didn't work for me.' do you realize this provides us with ZERO information and just makes it more difficult to try and help you?  WHAT answer, WHAT post, WHAT did you try.  Edit your question and provide more info, until you do that, you have one of the worst questions asked so far this week.  People are here, spending their time for free trying to help others, but we can't do a thing with nothing to work from.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot find the file `ove_scenario.rb`.  The error originates on line 3 of driver.rb. Without seeing code and knowing what the file is named and where it is kept, it is hard to tell you why

- could be that you spelled something wrong and no file by that name
  exists
- could be a bad path is being specified
- could be the file is not in current directory and a path needs to be specified in the require statement or you need to set the RUBYLIB environment variable so the file can be found.

Answer (score 0):

your driver.rb file should contain the following

```
 require 'watir'

 require_relative 'file_1'
 require_relative 'file_2'  
 require_relative 'file_3'
```

make sure the files are in the same directory as the driver.rb file
when you do the require_relative lines the file name does not need to have the ".rb" extension after it